# Java HTTP post for XML SOAP message

Tags: java, xml, http, soap, message

How to expose / publish services using Java HTTP post for XML SOAP message.
What are all steps need to follow.
I did googling but haven't found any thing about exposing / publishing services.

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript? And what do you mean "HTTP Post"?

Comment: I mean Java. HTTP post means - How to transmit XML SOAP message on HTTP connection.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good place to start: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/